# spinner with setOnItemSelectedListener doesn't execute methods

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have created a spinner and it takes it's values from some database. The spinner also has a setOnItemSelectedListener which executes a method. Whenever I click on an item on the spinner i doesn't execute what's inside of it.

```
    //Getting values from database
    myDBJ = new JobDatabaseHelper(this);
    ArrayList<String> jobname= myDBJ.getalljobname();

    Spinner spinnerJob = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerJob);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterForJob = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InfoActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, jobname);
    adapterForJob.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapterForJob.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerJob.setAdapter(adapterForJob);
    spinnerJob.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(InfoActivity.this, "test" + i ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //refreshrate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

I have even made a toast message inside of it so that I will know if it worked. When i click on an item it doesn't show the toast message. Another detail I would like to add is that this inside a method called "refreshspinners" which is called in my onCreate and my onPostResume override methods.

Comment: The [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner) says "The choices you provide for the spinner (...) must be provided through an [SpinnerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter), such as (...) a [CursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter) if the choices are available from a database query". It seems it's your case. Try with a CursorAdapter instead of an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: What is jobname and how many items are there in the spinner?

Comment: please add the creation of jobname with the question

Comment: jobname is an arraylist. It gets it's values form a database. Also the spinner works just fine, it's just the onItemSelectedListener not triggering

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with a static String list:

```
ArrayList<String> jobname = (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Engineer", "Manager", "Business developer"});

Spinner spinnerJob = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerJob);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterForJob = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InfoActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, jobname);
adapterForJob.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerJob.setAdapter(adapterForJob);

spinnerJob.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(InfoActivity.this, "test" + i ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //refreshrate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I can't use a static String list because the database is always changing.

Comment: Just for the test

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner)       findViewById(R.id.spnner);
        ArrayList<String> list = myDBJ.getAllJobName();
     sp.setAdapter(new       ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list));

        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int p3, long p4)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),list.get(p3),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> p1)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
            }
        });
```